# WebApp: How to Use Icons, Colors ... of the Native User Interface

Tags: html, web-applications, user-interface, css

I'm just getting started working on a WebApp which should behave like a native one. That's why I don't want to create my own theme, but I want to use theme of the User Interface (Unity [Ubuntu], Explorer [Windows], Gnome [Mint] and so on) the user uses.

These are some things I want to take from the UI's theme:

- **Icons**: "Save", "Open", "Copy", "Paste" and such icons
- **Positions**: Windows applications draw the "OK"-button on the left-hand-side, and the "Cancel"-button on the right-hand-side and for Ubuntu users it's converse. Another example: Ubuntu users can find the menu entry of application settings at "Edit" and Windows users can find it at "Extras".
- **Naming conventions**: Some things like "Folder" vs. "Directory" are called differently.
- **Colors and backgrounds**: The background of the menu bar is showed gray to Unity/Ubuntu users and it's shown lavender to Explorer/Windows7 users.

**I know that not every thing which I talked about will be possible.** But I want to solve at least some of these problems. Here are some solutions I heard about:

- **(-moz-)appearance** (obsolete [CSS3 darft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/CR-css3-ui-20040511/))
- **CSS System Colors** like ButtonText or Window (deprecated, but avaible in many browsers)
- **CSS System fonts** (obsolete [CSS3 darft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/CR-css3-ui-20040511/))

My Question: Do you know other scopes to take Colors, Icons ... from the User Interface?

Comment: You're not going to have that kind of access to the UI of the host.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I don't need direct access. I just need interfaces (like -moz-appearance or CSS System Colors) to get information about the User Interface.

Comment: I recommend you install the Windows 8 Consumer Preview somewhere and look at a rather different system user interface. See whether you still think that you'll be able to get a single abstraction over user interface themes. You may or may not then want to consider UI of Unix or Macintosh systems.

Comment: @JohnSaunders There won't be enough possibilities to write an UI for such different UI concepts (like Metro/Windows8 vs. Explorer/Windows8). -moz-appearance helps me creating an UI for akin UIs like Unity/Ubuntu vs. Explorer/Windows7, but it isn't strong enough to provide platform specific icons or such things. And I want to find a way to do these things.

Comment: Just making sure you understood that. You might mimic _certain_ user interfaces, but not even a majority of them.

Comment: I can use CSS System Colors (to get the right font color), CSS System Metrics (to find out if the user is using the graphite or the windows theme). CSS System Fonts (to get the right font) and (-moz-)appearance (to use elements provided by the system).

Comment: @JohnSaunders I know, i know :-L

Comment: I use CSS System Metrics to detect if the user uses the Mac Graphite theme. But it doesn't help me to know that if I can't access the Mac System-Provided-Icons.

Comment: So: I want to get infos about the version of OSX using the navigator object and then download the right set of Mac System-Provided Icons. Is there any web service where i can get OSX system icons?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can use are the CSS System Colors - everything else could be guessed at by User Agent sniffing, but it will only be a guess.

Answer (score 0):

For the icons, you can use moz-icon. Example:

```
#content a[href $=".pdf"]:before {
    content: url("moz-icon://.pdf");
}
```

This works only on Firefox and Gecko-based browsers.